# Can you edit modern pages with the graph api

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, microsoft-graph, graph-api

I am able to create and publish new modern pages in SharePoint Online using the graph api https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sitepage-create?view=graph-rest-beta .

However I can't seem to figure out how to edit existing pages. Am I missing something really obvious or does the functionality not exist?

I have tried doing another post to the create endpoint and it says that a page with that name already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Pages are list items under the covers, and you can [update list items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). You'll need to figure out the properties to modify and the correct syntax for doing so but in theory it's there.